# search keyword display dropdown list two columns

Tags: excel, search, dropdownlistfor

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Sheet2:**

[image]

**Question:**
Is it possible to create a searchable Dropdown list in Sheet1 A6 that displays a list of combined Sheet2’s ColA+ColB. And the ColB of the selected row will be the value of Sheet1 B2.

i.e.
If type in a keyword ‘apple’ on Sheet1 A6, Sheet1 A6 cell will have a dropdown list of Sheet2 A2-B5.
Then the user will select a row from this dropdown and Sheet1 B2 will display the price (ColB) of the selected value.

Please let me know if this makes sense.
Thanks.

Comment: Much easier to put a data validation drop-down in cell **A6** and use a *VLOOKUP()* formula in cell **B2** to retrieve the correct price based on what was picked in **A6**.

Comment: wouldn't this way display the whole range of list in Sheet2? I only want to display the list based on the search keyword in cell A6 Sheet1.

Comment: You cannot have a search input in the same cell as a data validation list based on the results of that search.  You can however search from one box and put the results in a data validation list in another cell.  This requires some helper columns in the list of items to handle searching.

Comment: is there any example tutorials or videos for this?

Comment: I think your looking for a user form? that invokes special filter by "contains" ? is that the case? - by that i mean one enters apple and gets all the apples to choose from?

Comment: There is a very good video on searchable drop-down lists found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkPoViUhkxU&index=42&list=WL You will need some helper columns, but it will work. I've used it myself. It can also be used for multiple drop-down lists. See the part2 video. Hope that helps.